# How to give Form-param, both values and files in a http request in python

Tags: python-3.x, http

I wanna make a http request as shown in the below curl command:

```
curl -X PUT \
https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/cloudhub/api/v2/applications/highfiles \
-H 'authorization: Bearer XXX' \
-H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
-H 'content-length: 0' \
-H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
-H 'host: anypoint.mulesoft.com' \
-H 'postman-token: XXX' \
-H 'x-anypnt-env-id: XXX' \
-H 'x-anypnt-org-id: XXX' \
-F 'appInfoJson={
"muleVersion": {
    "version": "3.8.5"
},
"properties":{"env":"dev"}
}'
```

I have tried the below request but all vain

```
files = {'file': open('C:\Users\\highfiles.zip', 'rb')}
    appInfoJson1 = {
        "muleVersion": {
            "version": "3.8.5"
        },
        "properties": {"env":"dev1"}
    }
    print dict(appInfoJson=appInfoJson1)
    headers = {"X-ANYPNT-ORG-ID": "XXXX",
               "X-ANYPNT-ENV-ID": "XXXX",
               "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token,
               }
    response = requests.put("https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/cloudhub/api/v2/applications/highfiles",
                            data=dict(appInfoJson=appInfoJson1) , files=files, headers = headers)
```

How do I give a form-Param values and file in a python http request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing it wrong.

The change was only w.r.t handling the dict values, shown below:

response = requests.put("https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/cloudhub/api/v2/applications/highfiles",
                            data=dict(appInfoJson=appInfoJson1.values()) , files=files, headers = headers)